# Naming Definitions and Tables in Appendix

Tags: numbering, appendices

I have a question regarding the `appendix` environment. Consider the following example:

```
\documentclass[10 pt,a4paper,oneside,openany, notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, graphics}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\marginparwidth 0pt
\oddsidemargin 0pt
\evensidemargin 0pt
\marginparsep 0pt
\linespread{1.5}
\topmargin 0pt
\textwidth 6.5in
\textheight 8.5 in
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{bigints}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage[multiple]{footmisc}
\usepackage{xr}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}


\begin{document}
\begin{appendix}
\counterwithin{theorem}{section}

\section{supplement 1}

\begin{equation}
2x=6
\end{equation}

\begin{definition}
blah blah
\end{definition}
\section{supplement 2}

\begin{table} [ht]
\caption{Descriptive statistics. All definitions are illustrated above.}
\centering
{\scriptsize
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline  
2 & 2\\
3 & 3\\
\hline
\end{tabular}}
\label{statistics_appendix}
\end{table}


\end{appendix}
\end{document}
```

How can I get the Definition named Definition A.1 instead of Definition 1 and the Table named Table B.1 instead of Table 1?

Comment: `openany` is no option to `article.cls`

Comment: The same way you already do with `\counterwithin{theorem}{section}`?! By the way: no need for the `chngcntr` package: `amsmath` provides `\numberwithin` which does the same as `\counterwithin` (but I assume you already know that – you're using `\numberwithin{equation}{section}`…)

Comment: Setting margins like that is not very LaTeX-like. I'd rather use the `geometry` package… also I believe that `appendix` is no environment but a macro to be used as switch `\appendix`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use

```
\counterwithin{definition}{section}
\counterwithin{table}{section}
```

as has been done with `theorem` already!

```
\documentclass[10 pt,a4paper,oneside, notitlepage]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, graphics}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
%\marginparwidth 0pt
%\oddsidemargin 0pt
%\evensidemargin 0pt
%\marginparsep 0pt
%\linespread{1.5}
%\topmargin 0pt
%\textwidth 6.5in
%\textheight 8.5 in
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\usepackage{bigints}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage[multiple]{footmisc}
\usepackage{xr}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\numberwithin{equation}{section}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xapptocmd{\appendix}{%
  \counterwithin{theorem}{section}
  \counterwithin{definition}{section}
  \counterwithin{table}{section}
}{\typeout{Success}}{}



\begin{document}


\appendix

\section{supplement 1}

\begin{equation}
2x=6
\end{equation}

\begin{definition}
blah blah
\end{definition}
\section{supplement 2}

\begin{table} [ht]
\caption{Descriptive statistics. All definitions are illustrated above.}
\centering
{\scriptsize
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline  
2 & 2\\
3 & 3\\
\hline
\end{tabular}}
\label{statistics_appendix}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I would put these declarations in the preamble, with `\AtBeginEnvironment`.

Comment: @Bernard: Thanks for the suggestion, I've put it into `\AtBeginEnvironment`

Comment: I know it works but IIRC `appendix` is not really an environment but a switch (`\appendix`)

Comment: The O.P.'s code uses the `appendix` environment…

Comment: @clemens: I confused it with `appendices`. Now, the changes (regardless whether `\counterwithin` or `\numberwithin` are used are appended (sic!) to `\appendix`, this works either way: `\appendix` or `\begin{appendix}`

Comment: @Bernard I know…

Comment: @Christian Hupfer: More specifically, the `apptools` package provides the `\AtAppendix` command.